# "Merging" ids together in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `cities` like this:

| id | city |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Vancouver |
| 2 | Calgary |
| 3 | Calgry |

And multiple other tables which reference `cities`, something like this (just some example numbers).

| id | city_id | year | population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2000 | 100000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2001 | 130000 |
| 3 | 3 | 2000 | 70000 |
| 4 | 3 | 2001 | 85000 |
| 5 | 2 | 2002 | 95000 |

I want to merge/consolidate city id 3 into id 2, so change every occurrence of id 3 across all tables to 2, and then delete city id 3. Is there a clean way of doing this?

Something like `ON UPDATE CASCADE` would work perfectly but I can't have duplicate primary ids. At the very least I could loop through the foreign keys and run a query on every table but I'm not sure if there's a more idiomatic way.

Answer (score 2):

`ON UPDATE CASCADE` causes duplicate PK. To avoid that, we can use `ON DELETE SET NULL` which nullify all the city_id with a value 3 in other tables once we delete the city_id 3 from the cities table, but then you would still have to change the city_id from null to 2 in the said tables. This is not fundamentally different to **change those city_id with a value 3 to 2 for the other tables , then just delete id 3 from the cities table**.  If you feel  reluctant to manually do that or if there are too many tables to handle, then use a procedure. Make a list of table , declare a cursor for the list and loop through the list to get each table name and use a prepared statement to do the UPDATE.

Comment: If I have to change all the tables anyways that's just making an unnecessary extra step like you say... SET NULL is an interesting idea though.